# Filter JS Program not working

Tags: javascript, html

I am attempting to create a web app that allows you to select emails in order to send a blast message. I want a filter to allow the user to pick between a mix of Scouts, Parents, and Leaders to grab their emails. I cannot figure out why the code will not work, I think it has something to do with the JavaScript end, but I'm not sure. The goal is for the "filter" check boxes to check all boxes in the table that have the target data-type and vice-versa when unchecked (ex when "Leader" is selected, all of the "Leader" data-type check boxes get checked in the table.  Before, I attempted to filter by making the rows display as none and assigning the whole row to the data-type, and that worked, however, I forgot to back up that code.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<div class = "SelectionContainer">
<div class = "FiltersContainer">
   <ul id="filters">
      <li>
         <input type='checkbox' name='Filter' value="Leader" id="filter-Leader">
         <label for="filter-Leader">Leaders</label>
      </li>
      <li>
         <input type='checkbox' name='Filter' value="Parent" id = "filter-Parent"> 
         <label for="filter-Parent">Parents</label>
      </li>
      <li>
         <input type='checkbox' name='Filter' value="Scout" id = "filter-Scout"> 
         <label for="filter-Scout">Scouts</label>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
<div class = "EmailsContainer">
   <form action = "broadcasting.php" method = "get">
      <table class = 'hubTable' id = 'FilterTarget'>
         <tr class = 'tableheader'>
            <td class = 'hubCell'>Email</td>
            <td class = 'hubCell'>Name</td>
            <td class = 'hubCell'>Type</td>
            <td class = 'hubCell'>Subtype</td>
         </tr>
         <tr class = 'hubRow' >
            <td class = 'hubCell'><input class = 'hubCheck' type='checkbox' data-type='Scout' name='check_list[]' value='mikeb@web.net'  > mikeb@we.net </td>
            <td class = 'hubCell'>Biden, Mike </td>
            <td class = 'hubCell' id = 'Type'>Scout </td>
            <td class = 'hubCell' id = 'SubType'>Senior Patrol Leader </td>
         </tr>
         <tr class = 'hubRow' >
            <td class = 'hubCell'><input class = 'hubCheck' type='checkbox' data-type='Parent' name='check_list[]' value='sueb@gmail.com'  > sueb@gmail.com </td>
            <td class = 'hubCell'>Biden, Sue </td>
            <td class = 'hubCell' id = 'Type'>Parent </td>
            <td class = 'hubCell' id = 'SubType'>Unassigned </td>
         </tr>
         <tr class = 'hubRow' >
            <td class = 'hubCell'><input class = 'hubCheck' type='checkbox' data-type='Leader' name='check_list[]' value='msmith@me.com'  > msmith@me.com </td>
            <td class = 'hubCell'>smith, Michael </td>
            <td class = 'hubCell' id = 'Type'>Leader </td>
            <td class = 'hubCell' id = 'SubType'>Scout Master </td>
         </tr>
         <tr class = 'hubRow' >
            <td class = 'hubCell'><input class = 'hubCheck' type='checkbox' data-type='Scout' name='check_list[]' value='russel.gill@domain.org'  > russel.gill@suffieldstudent.org </td>
            <td class = 'hubCell'>Gill, Russel </td>
            <td class = 'hubCell' id = 'Type'>Scout </td>
            <td class = 'hubCell' id = 'SubType'>Patrol Leader </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </form>
</div>
```

I tried to filter using the data-type tag withing the input box so that JS could find it. My JS code looks like this:

```
var filterTarget = document.querySelectorAll(".hubCheck input[type="checkbox"]");
var filters = document.querySelectorAll("#filters li");

for (var i = 0; i < filters.length; i++){
    filters[i].addEventListener("click", filterItems, false);
    filters[i].checked = true;
}
function filterItems(e){
    var clickedItem = e.target;
    if (clickedItem.checked == true) {
    document.getElementById("checkbox").checked = true;
    } else if (clickedItem.checked == false) {
        document.getElementById("checkbox").checked = false;
    } else {

    }
}
```

I believe the error to be somewhere in the JS as I am not as well versed in the language as I am with HTML and PHP. A set of smarter and more experienced eyes would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: think you need to set .checked on the filterTarget(input checkbox) instead of the filters(li). the getElementById also isn't targetting the checkbox (which each have their own id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are having is because of **document.getElementById("checkbox").checked** syntax as there is no id with checkbox. and you are not comparing with data-type value. i would suggest you to use what you put in your data-type put it on class name also.

my solution HTML

```
<div class = "SelectionContainer">
<div class = "FiltersContainer">
   <ul id="filters">
      <li>
         <input type='checkbox' name='Filter' value="Leader" id="filter-Leader">
         <label for="filter-Leader">Leaders</label>
      </li>
      <li>
         <input type='checkbox' name='Filter' value="Parent" id = "filter-Parent"> 
         <label for="filter-Parent">Parents</label>
      </li>
      <li>
         <input type='checkbox' name='Filter' value="Scout" id = "filter-Scout"> 
         <label for="filter-Scout">Scouts</label>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
<div class = "EmailsContainer">
   <form action = "broadcasting.php" method = "get">
      <table class = 'hubTable' id = 'FilterTarget'>
         <tr class = 'tableheader'>
            <td class = 'hubCell'>Email</td>
            <td class = 'hubCell'>Name</td>
            <td class = 'hubCell'>Type</td>
            <td class = 'hubCell'>Subtype</td>
         </tr>
         <tr class = 'hubRow' >
            <td class = 'hubCell'><input class = 'hubCheck Scout' type='checkbox' data-type='Scout' name='check_list[]' value='mikeb@web.net'  > mikeb@we.net </td>
            <td class = 'hubCell'>Biden, Mike </td>
            <td class = 'hubCell' id = 'Type'>Scout </td>
            <td class = 'hubCell' id = 'SubType'>Senior Patrol Leader </td>
         </tr>
         <tr class = 'hubRow' >
            <td class = 'hubCell'><input class = 'hubCheck Parent' type='checkbox' data-type='Parent' name='check_list[]' value='sueb@gmail.com'  > sueb@gmail.com </td>
            <td class = 'hubCell'>Biden, Sue </td>
            <td class = 'hubCell' id = 'Type'>Parent </td>
            <td class = 'hubCell' id = 'SubType'>Unassigned </td>
         </tr>
         <tr class = 'hubRow' >
            <td class = 'hubCell'><input class = 'hubCheck Leader' id="asd" type='checkbox' data-type='Leader' name='check_list[]' value='msmith@me.com'  > msmith@me.com </td>
            <td class = 'hubCell'>smith, Michael </td>
            <td class = 'hubCell' id = 'Type'>Leader </td>
            <td class = 'hubCell' id = 'SubType'>Scout Master </td>
         </tr>
         <tr class = 'hubRow' >
            <td class = 'hubCell'><input class = 'hubCheck Scout' type='checkbox' data-type='Scout' name='check_list[]' value='russel.gill@domain.org'  > russel.gill@suffieldstudent.org </td>
            <td class = 'hubCell'>Gill, Russel </td>
            <td class = 'hubCell' id = 'Type'>Scout </td>
            <td class = 'hubCell' id = 'SubType'>Patrol Leader </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </form>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var filterTarget = document.querySelectorAll('.hubCheck input[type="checkbox"]');
var filters = document.querySelectorAll("#filters li");

for (var i = 0; i < filters.length; i++){
    filters[i].addEventListener("click", filterItems, false);
    filters[i].checked = true;
}
function filterItems(e){
    var clickedItem = e.target;

    if (clickedItem.checked == true) {
    var elem= document.getElementsByClassName(clickedItem.value);
    checkboxupdater(elem, true);

} else if (clickedItem.checked == false) {
var elem= document.getElementsByClassName(clickedItem.value);
         checkboxupdater(elem, false);
    } else {

    }
}

function checkboxupdater(ele,val)
{
  for(var ii = 0; ii < ele.length; ii++)
  {
    ele[ii].checked = val;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, that was the issue, and adding the class was a clever idea! Thanks again!